# Cocoa Controller imports Model, Model imports Controller --> Exception

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, model-view-controller, import

why isn't it possible in Cocoa that two Classes both import each other?
I tried the following code:

Controller.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "Model.h"

@interface Controller : NSObject {
 Model *model;
}

@end
```

Model.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "Controller.h"

@interface Model : NSObject {
 Controller *controller;
}

@end
```

which raises the following exceptions:

```
error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'Controller'
error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'Model'
```

Can someone please explain why this is?

Thanks!
xonic

Comment: This is not technically an "exception" (which is a run-time event), it's a compiler error message.

Comment: The "why" is fairly straightforward in this case, and you can see it for yourself if you mentally expand the #import to put one file's text into the other: you import the definition of Model before you define Controller, but that definition uses Controller. And vice versa. There is a circular dependency, so one will *always* have not been defined before the other. This is why the @class declaration exists: it simply says "I'll define this later, in the meantime don't worry about it." That breaks the cycle, et voila.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explain why?  No.

But the solution is to use the @class declaration like so:

```
@class Model;
@interface Controller : NSObject {
 Model *model;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution for this is that:
Model.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "Controller.h"

@class Controller;
@interface Model : NSObject {
 Controller *controller;
}

@end
```

And you done with that